# Python: What is the purpose of this sign % and when should I use it?

Tags: python

Im kind of having trouble understanding the use of this sign %, I thought its only for solving remainders in python but I saw my prof using this to print a statement. Here's an example code that I dont get;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUiBr.png)

in the image, i dont get the highlighted in red text which is the use of **`%d`** and `**%.3f**` Is the letter `d` fixed? or i can use any other alphabet characters for that? What and when can I use it? What is it called in python so that maybe i can searched it on youtube

Comment: Python uses C-style string formatting to create new, formatted strings. The "%" operator is used to format a set of variables enclosed in a "tuple" (a fixed size list), together with a format string, which contains normal text together with "argument specifiers", special symbols like "%s" and "%d". link: https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of Percent sign in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764897/what-is-the-meaning-of-percent-sign-in-python) ; or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting

Comment: This is the oldest string formatting option in Python. You would be better off investigating about `f-strings` which are the most up-to-date way of formatting strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a placeholder, %d for decimal value, %f for float, %s for string etc.. used for injecting in formatted string.

For more usage see: [What's the difference between %s and %d in Python string formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting)